# Counting measure and Lebesgue intregal

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider $$ f: \mathbb {N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$

I want to compute the Lebesgue integral with counting measure.

$$ \int_N f d \mu $$

Why does it make sense to integrate over N and not for example R?

Comment: Go through definition

Comment: Because your measure space is $\mathbb N.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure?wprov=sfti1) can be defined on any $(A, \mathcal P(A))$. See Wikipedia article for more details.

Now, if your function $f$ is only defined on $\mathbb N$, the integral will only make sense on $\mathbb N$ also. And its value will be $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} f(n)$.

Comment: Ok, when  f is defined on R, what would I get instead?

Comment: You would get $\int_{\mathbb R} f$... but knowing that $\int$ isn’t in that case the Lebesgue integral but $\int_{\mathbb R} f =\sum_{x \in \mathbb R} f(x)$ with the meaning of $\sum$ provided in the Wikipedia article I referenced. In particular, as soon as $f$ has an uncountable number of non vanishing values, $\int \vert  f\vert  =\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much:)